# Hiding Your IP on Linux

Tags: ip

I've always been a Linux fan but I find it so surprising that unlike Windows, it doesn't have software like Real Hide My IP which is a software that allows you to select a country, change your IP and more. In the back of my mind, I know there has to be SOMETHING OUT THERE, that isn't "browser based." Anything from a browser like Tor is weak and useless. You can still be traced. It isn't that I want to use these tools, I just want to learn anything and everything and I like testing things out.

Comment: You're never untraceable.

Comment: A quick glance at RHIP's site leaves me with the distinct impression that it's a scaremongering bullshit to tempt easily frightened idiots into spending money. Especially since at least two of their claims *are not how the internet works*.

Comment: That's true. Both points are accurate. I was curious. That's actually pretty interesting.

Comment: TOR is useless? can you still be traced? could you please elaborate that affirmation?

Comment: -1 for "tor is useless." Tor _is_ exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: A Question (as on this site) should normally have a question: i.e. a sentence ending in a question mark (as is custom in the English language that we use here). What is your question? What have you tried that is not working? What was the (incorrect) output of what you tried. What did you expect?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I am concerned, I find `tor` extremely simple to configure for simple proxying or VPN use.

> I've always been a Linux fan but I find it so surprising that unlike Windows, it doesn't have software like Real Hide My IP which is a software that allows you to select a country, change your IP and [...]

Linux is not Windows. There is such software*, but don't expect it to come in your usual `exe` format, ready to be clicked and launched. However, many Linux distributions will provide a `torsocks` package, which allows you to proxy any application through the ToR network, as long as it is using a TCP-based protocol (HTTP, POP3, IMAP, ...).

<sup>* Edit: actually no, there is no such thing as Real Hide my IP. But there is software which does what your looking for. I couldn't seriously compare ToR and this "thing". However, I do understand why *this* is available on Windows, and Windows only. If you believe that Real Hide my IP provides better service than the ToR network, then you definitely don't understand what you're looking for.</sup>

On my Ubuntu system, I was able to install all of this in a single `apt-get` call.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tor torsocks
```

Now, once you've made sure that the `tor` daemon is running (`service tor status`), you're ready to use `torsocks` to proxify your browser, your mail client, and so on:

```
$ torsocks chromium-browser
$ torsocks thunderbird
...
```

After a quick search, I was able to find the `torsocks` package for [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/torsocks/), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/torsocks) and [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/torsocks/). There's even [a FreeBSD port for it](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net/torsocks/)! Linux could hardly make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

Untraceable ? There is no such a thing, but you can delay the time.

First you should check VPN stuff, For me I'd suggest [openVPN](https://openvpn.net/), it is quite common nowadays.